# Swift variables and memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I use storyboard segue for navigating throughout the application. And I declare string variables for `segue identifier` and `table cell identifier`. So I won't make any typo within the view controller class.

```
import UIKit

private let showTripViewSegueIdentifier = "showTripView"
private let contactCellIdentifier = "contactCell"

class JobViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
}
```

Would it affect memory usage for the application? (since there will be a lot of view controllers for the whole app). Is it a good approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please expand your question and supporting details. The wording is quite unclear :( I have read your question three times, and still don't see the actual question you are asking :(

Answer (score 1):

It won't make a significant difference. The strings have to be stored somewhere regardless, because you use them at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a enum like this:

enum SegueIdentifier: String {
    case SegueIdentifier1
    case SegueIdentifier2
    case SegueIdentifier3
}

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't really make a difference. However, a better approach would be to use an enum as also mentioned by Arun above.

Eg -

```
enum SegueIdentifier{
    case showTripView
    case contactCell
}
```

and use it in your code with the help of the shorter dot syntax. eg - `.contactCell`